# SendGrid - formatDate with Insert tag definition - Error

Tags: sendgrid

I am trying to format the date using formatDate. None of the options is working in terms of formatting the date. Please suggest. We are using the insert tag to fetch values from the template.

```
{{insert notes_lead_creation_date}}
```

This date has to be formatted to DD/MM/YYYY. Currently the date has : `notes_lead_creation_date:2058-07-25`

Also, getting an error message.

> This message has been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, [you cannot format a date within an `insert` helper](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/adding-dynamic-content-with-handlebars-in-marketing-campaigns#defaults-without-the-insert-keyword). If you are using `insert` to provide a fallback, you should use a conditional, like so:

```
{{#if notes_lead_creation_date}}
  {{ formatDate notes_lead_creation_date "DD/MM/YYYY"}}
{{else}}
  default content
{{/if}}
```

Note that [the date must be provided in ISO8601 format](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#formatdate) too.

Comment: I have tried this option as well. I get an error message in the Activity log and need to know the cause of it.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Message ID bxlG5Y5WSeCDGeL8Gr8QSg.filterdrecv-66b95c5ffd-qmp94-1-62E7988A-1B.0


 Dropped

2022/08/01 9:10am UTC+00:00

This email could not be sent.

Comment: If I just add {{insert notes_lead_creation_date}}, I get an output of 2058-07-25 and the notification doesn't fail. But the moment, I add #if, it errors out with the above message. If I add #each it doesn't provide any date in output but the message doesn't fail.  So not sure, how to fix this.

Comment: Can you share the data that you are sending and the exact template that you are using when you get the error? Also, have you tried entering the template into the SendGrid template editor and adding some data to test there? That might help!

Comment: Please let me know, how to share you the templates? Can I share internal ids here? Do you have email where I can send the content?

Comment: Before you send me anything, why not try the SendGrid template editor to see if that shows you the error?